# How to autolayout this scroll view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working with this app: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13541/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-22 there is a screen called stream screen that lists jpegs in a UIScrollView named list view. The apps was made for iPhone originally so the author has the storyboards set up for iPhone. How can I resize the list view to fit both iPhones and iPads while scaling the contentt?

Additional info: the storyboard has one uiscrollview. Right now i have the size set to 1192 height 1080 width because I am testing on an iPad and this are the previous dimensions I've used successfully. However when the screen itself loads , it only takes up about a 3rd of the width of the total UIScrollView.

***update***

```
//photoscreen.h
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//1 layout config
#define kThumbSide 90
#define kPadding 10
//2 define the thumb delegate protocol
@protocol PhotoViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)didSelectPhoto:(id)sender;
@end
//3 define the thumb view interface
@interface PhotoView : UIButton
{
}
@property (assign, nonatomic) id<PhotoViewDelegate> delegate;
-(id)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data;
@end


//this code is from photoview,which acts as a delegate for stream screen.m likewise, it formats the streams quality such as picture spacing

#import "PhotoView.h"
#import "API.h"

@implementation PhotoView

@synthesize delegate;

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

-(id)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data {
self = [super init];
if (self !=nil) {
    //initialize
    self.tag = [[data objectForKey:@"IdPhoto"] intValue];
    int row = i/3;
    int col = i % 3;
    self.frame = CGRectMake(1.5*kPadding+col*(kThumbSide+kPadding), 1.5*kPadding+row*(kThumbSide+kPadding), kThumbSide, kThumbSide);
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    //add the photo caption
    UILabel* caption = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, kThumbSide-16, kThumbSide, 16)];
    caption.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    caption.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caption.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    caption.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[data objectForKey:@"username"]];
    [self addSubview: caption];
    //add touch event
    [self addTarget:delegate action:@selector(didSelectPhoto:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //load the image
    API* api = [API sharedInstance];
    int IdPhoto = [[data objectForKey:@"IdPhoto"] intValue];
    NSURL* imageURL = [api urlForImageWithId:[NSNumber numberWithInt: IdPhoto] isThumb:YES];
    AFImageRequestOperation* imageOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL] success:^(UIImage *image) {
        //create an image view, add it to the view
        UIImageView* thumbView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
        thumbView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,90,90);
        thumbView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self insertSubview: thumbView belowSubview: caption];
    }];
    NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperation:imageOperation];
}
return self;

}

@end
```

Comment: the question your asking isn't specific to the tutorial you list -- it's a much broader design goal. you should first try to look up things like autolayout and size classes. learn the topics and then try to apply them. when you get stuck in the code, come here and post where it is you're stuck. otherwise, you're likely not going to get a response.

Comment: good idea. update ahead